# Refine usability and experience in repetitive mandatory task

Tags: usability, touch-screen

We have a requirement for an app in which the user needs to visualize a document, sign it and visualize it again with the signature on it. The problem comes when the process generates multiple documents.

Since the product has a hardware problem that makes signing very difficult the option now is to re-use the signature in every document generated, but in order to stay "in the law" (it is a financial product), the user needs to be able to actively approve or disapprove the reutilization of his signature, and obviously be able to review every document individually before and after they have been signed.

Any idea?

More info > it is navigated through a 21 inches touch display
Right now the user cannot sign directly on the document, we show the doc through pdf viewer and display a dedicated space for the signature, after that the document is reloaded with the signature placed on it.

Answer (score 1):

Docusign has a solution to this problem in their application. They store your signature and you manually approve/remove each instance where it is can be applied. You can move back and forth through the document and approve/remove any of your signatures. The interface is a simple acknowledgment over each blank signature field where you approval is necessary.

I think the ideal interface here would allow the user to navigate between generated documents, where they are led to the required signature fields and can approve the use of their signature. They would be able to move back and forth through the document(s) freely as well as having an indication of where their signatures are still required for completion. Once every signature has been filled I would have a strong visual indicator that they are complete and can submit their documents.

Answer (score 0):

If in order to follow the law, a user must review and approve a signed version of a document, then there is no other option but to enforce such behavior, even if there is an array of the documents to sign.

It is important to allow to do it the most convenient way possible, considering a factors like:

- Absence of scrolling necessity (e.g. header, signature, etc. are visible if required by the law);
- Absence of moving cursor necessity (e.g. if documents are shaped in different aspect ratios or sizes, the approving button should be placed at the same location on user's screen);
- Absence of waiting of document loading (prefetching documents in advance, prior an approve solution made by a user).

For sure, if the law ameliorated it's right to implement signing a batch of documents at once.

Answer (score 0):

It might help  right then to aid the user in knowing why you're asking them for something the "computer already knows".

For example, after the signature is attached, highlight it, and put a pair of controls next to it:

```
[check] Yes, sign this document
[ex]    Cancel, go back
```

Make it really easy to tap the "yes" button. Now the user both understands that there is an affirmative action they're taking, and are given a choice (which makes them more engaged)--even if you expect 99.9% of the time, they'll check the checkmark.